# HTML table empty tr

Tags: html

I have a problem about showing empty tr in table.

This code :

```html
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan=2>test</td>
  <td rowspan=2>test</td>
  <td rowspan=2>test</td>
  <td rowspan=2>test</td>
  <td rowspan=2>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
```

The last `<tr>` is not displayed because there is no `<td>` but the previous `<tr>` (with rowspans) is displayed only on one line.

**Edit : solution found https://jsfiddle.net/nrf1r6mg/1/**

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? if its just a larger height on your second row, use css..

Comment: rows means rows, not lines. The height is still calculated based on the size of the content, not the number of rows it takes up.

Comment: Writing valid HTML — https://validator.w3.org/nu/ — is usually a good idea too

Comment: This is an example code but on my real code I have others <tr> with <td> and the tr with rowspan is not displayed on 2 rows

Comment: What do you mean displayed only on one line? What is the intended result?

Comment: The <td> with rowspan is supposed to be shown on 2 rows, but the last <tr> is empty so it is displayed only on 1 row

Comment: You can see an example here https://jsfiddle.net/nrf1r6mg/. The <tr> after the rowspans is not displayed

Comment: I solved my problem with **visibility:hidden** https://jsfiddle.net/nrf1r6mg/1/

Comment: Please post an actual answer providing the solution to help other users see that it could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by adding one more `<td>` with **visibility:hidden;**

[jsfiddle.net/nrf1r6mg/1](http://jsfiddle.net/nrf1r6mg/1)